# How to deselect button in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I've created my own minimize button in Windows Forms and handle `Click` event like in the following code:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
this.notifyIcon.Visible = true;
this.notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
```

Unfortunately, when the window restores to the normal state, this button has a selection on it:

[image]

Is there any way to avoid such behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your button gets the focus of course.  You're much better off *not* making it a button but just an image the you draw in OnPaint().  Then the form's MouseUp event is all you need, check e.Location.  Some sample code [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23139022/17034).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to avoid this, try it:

```
yourButton.TabStop = false;
yourButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
yourButton.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255); //Transparent
```

And if doesn't work, try this too: override ShowFocusCues property

```
protected override bool ShowFocusCues
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't make `BorderColor` transparent (at least from the designer)

Comment: take a look at this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8d85e6dd-18ad-4503-9f0a-731a8d73d570/removing-the-focus-rectangle-from-a-flat-button-when-the-form-itself-does-not-have-focus?forum=winforms)

Answer (score 0):

Some control usually has the focus.

You can decide which it should be and add `thatcontrol.Focus();` You need to add that  before the minimizing call:

```
 label1.Focus();
 this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

But imo, for the best user experience the `Focus` should be on a visible control so that the user knows just where he is. (I hate those webpages where I want to start typing but am nowhere..)